# How to click/use dynamically created buttons in android

Tags: android, button, click

I dynamically created 3 buttons, but I can't access these buttons via the `setOnClicklistener` method.
My code is below:

```
quesButton = new Button[3];


    ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll4button);

    for(int x=0; x<3; x++){
        quesButton[x] = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        quesButton[x].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        quesButton[x].setText("Q" + (x + 1));

        ll1.addView(quesButton[x]);
    }
```

Comment: Where you are adding the setOnClickListener in these buttons ?

Comment: From what you've shown us, you never even use `setOnClickListener`... Share the rest of the relevant code please.

Comment: I was trying to apply setOnclickListener outside the code above, but Tom Nijs answer has solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach an onClickListener AFTER your create a new element.

```
quesButton[x] = new Button(MainActivity.this);
...
quesButton[x].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{ 
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
    }
});
```